# Put the gear back in forward

Tags: idiomatic-language

I put the gear in reverse and backed out of the driveway, then I put the gear back in forward and drove off.

Do you say "put the gear back in forward"? or is there a more natural way to say this?

Comment: You can make it more natural and avoid all the 'back' awkwardness by omitting 'back' - _I put the gear in reverse and backed out of the driveway, then I put the gear in forward and drove off._

Comment: Even better: I selected reverse gear and backed out of the driveway, then changed to forward and drove away.

Comment: You didn't put the gear "back in forward" because it wasn't originally in that position.

Comment: You don't put a gear in anything, you put a gearbox in forward/reverse. Or car/vehicle...

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you speak of putting the vehicle in a particular gear, rather than putting the gear in a particular condition. The latter isn't wrong, it's just unusual.

For your sentence, I would say

> I put the car in reverse, backed out of the driveway, then put it in drive and drove off.

That's if the car has an automatic transmission. If it's  a manual transmission, you'd say

> I put it in first [gear] and drove off.

That refers to the first forward gear of a manual transmission car.
The word "gear" is optional in that sentence.

Comment: It may help to add that it would be correct (but still odd) to say that you "put the gear back in forward" if the gear had *previously been in forward* prior to being in reverse, which does not seem to be the case in the example sentence.